# Can't set new IMG event attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript, but have some experience of Java/C++. So, I'm trying to use the following code to set up some simple event attributes on a new IMG element that I am creating:

```
var square = document.createElement("IMG");
square.src = "Square_Empty.png";
square.alt = "Oops!";
square.style = "height:100px;width:100px;position:\
absolute;top:14.5px;left:83.1px;";
square.onmouseover = "this.src='Square_Red.png'";
square.onmouseout = "this.src='Square_Empty.png'";
document.body.appendChild(square);
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except the assignment of the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes. According to the debugger (Firefox), these attribute are not being assigned, but the other ones are, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `addEventListener()` :

```
square.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ this.src='Square_Red.png' });
square.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ this.src='Square_Empty.png' });
```

Or you could simply add anonymous function `function()` :

```
square.onmouseover = function(){ this.src='Square_Red.png'; }
square.onmouseout = function(){ this.src='Square_Empty.png'; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The event listener suggestion worked - thanks! I'm still curious though, as to why what I was trying to do didn't work. Seems like I should be able to assign those strings to the img attributes, in the same way as the other ones?

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could helps... you can't pass a string as event you should pass a function ..

Comment: Ok, but if I set it up directly in the html, it works if I just assign the string "this.src='Square_Red.png'" to the attribute. Maybe it works differently there?